# How can I fill the screen with a TextBlock in WPF, but get it to add scroller if bigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following piece of XAML code in my WPF application,

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}">Import Log</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Height="400" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock  Name="ImportFeedBack"></TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

which dispalys the `ImportFeedBack` string (in case someone is wondering, I'm using `Caliburn.Micro` as MVVM framework, so that the content of the `TextBlock` is bound by naming convention to a property of same name in my ViewModel).

The value can vary heavily in length. I want it to use the whole available space (but it should not resize the application!), and only if that is not enough, add a vertical scroll bar.

If I delete the `Height="400"` in the `ScrollViewer`, it resizes the app for big strings, and if I leave it there, it (obviously) just uses 400 height, but ads he scroll bar when needed.

How can I get it to use all the available space, and only if that is not enough, to creata a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Set the `ResizeMode` of the Window to `NoResize`.

Comment: But can the user then still resize the app as he wishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `StackPanel` use different panel like `Grid` or `DockPanel`. In the example below second row will take all available space not allocated by first row and not expand beyond that which is when scroll bar should appear when text is longer.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}">Import Log</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock  Name="ImportFeedBack"></TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. That almost works (I tried the `DockPanel` approach) - the first time I update the string it resizes the app to full screen height and then applies a `ScrollViewer`, if I then make the app smaller and request a new log, it stays that size and then applies a `ScrollViewer`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _it resizes the app to full screen height and then applies a ScrollViewer_? There is not resizing here.

Comment: Well, after launching the app has a height of, say 300. I click a button which updates the log string, and then the app instantly fills the screen vertically. The width remains the same. But since the log is even longer, it additionally adds a vertical scroll bar (which is good - before, with the `StackPanel`, the app even resized bigger than the screen!)

Comment: So then which bit is not working? What happens when your resize your app? What happens and what should happen? Width and/or Height is wrong?

Comment: Well, it should not ever resize the app when the content changes. So the first behaviour, when it resizes to full height is not wanted. As I said, if the user then resizes (by clicking the border and dragging with the mouse) that new size is respected by the app, and not changed.

Comment: This bit I don't understand in your problem. Window should not resize unless you set it to resize to content

Comment: Well, this code is in a `UserControl` coupled to a `ViewModel` deep in the app. Maybe the issue now is with the main window. I will check that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98916/discussion-between-dkozl-and-eluciusftw).